# Linking between SQL Server and Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, excel

I want to dump Excel data in SQL Server database. What is the best/easiest way to do this?

I have SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. I have tried many techniques but failed miserably, there is no option to connect a link between Excel and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I would be interested to hear what you have tried and what issues you have faced.

You say you have SSMS 2012 installed, but it's not clear if you have a database engine in which to host a database and associated tables?

If you do not have a database engine installed, you can install the SQL Express engine locally. Download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062).

You are going to need to import the data from Excel into a table within an existing SQL Server database.

To do this, you can use SSIS, if you have access to it, and create a simple ETL package involving a Source (Excel) and OLEDB Destination (SQL Server). You will need to create an existing table in your database, with appropriate fields and data-types, in which to 'dump' the data.

Or,

You can import the data through Management Studio directly, but you will need an existing database. Right click the database, click `Tasks --> Import Data`, and then follow the steps, selecting Excel Source and SQL Destination.